# Umbraco tinymce RTE not loading anymore

Tags: javascript, tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a project set up on umbraco 7.5.3 and everything worked fine.
However, since a few days, the TinyMce RTE doesn't load the content anymore.
It's giving me a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at f (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5)
at p (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5)
at new <anonymous> (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5)
at N.initContentBody (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:11)
at N.init (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:11)
at n.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:11)
at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5)
at a (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:2)
at h (tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5)
at tinymce.min.js?umb__rnd=7.5.3.1175360835:5
```

I've tried resetting the security for the app pool on the file system but no change. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yup, tinymce RTE is definitely not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems hard to find a solution in such a case.

But I think if you go to the umbraco.controller.js file (located in umbraco/js folder), you can debug this error by adding alerts.

This way you can exactly find the place from where this error is coming.

Hope this helps somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing your browser cache

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/59764-Umbraco-72-no-rich-text-editor-is-showing